# Check for string inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Anyway that I can check for string inside a string in javascript?

Example:
If I have 2 variable

```
var value1 = '|1|2|3|4|5|6'
var value2 = '1|2|3'
```

How can I check whether value2 is found in value1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var contained = (value1.indexOf(value2) != -1);
```

`contained` will be true if and only if `value2` is a substring of `value1`.

Comment: To be clear, this will return the 0-based index of the start of where value2 occurs within value1; it will return -1 if it is not found, so make sure to code any conditions accordingly.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

```
'|1|2|3|4|5|6'.match(/1\|2\|3/);
```

Note that you need to escape the `|`, since they have a special meaning in Regular Expressions. If this is too much of a hassle, [Matthews `indexOf` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151231/check-for-string-inside-a-string-in-javascript/4151239#4151239) is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use regular expressions and javascript's `.match()` method:

```
if(value1.match(/1\|2\|3/)) {
   // value2 is found in value1
}
```

`.match()` returns an array of the matches, or null if no matches are found.

Also note that the pipes, `|`, have to be escaped with a backslash, `\`, because they have special meaning within regular expressions. Specifically, they mean `OR`. So `/1|2/` becomes `1 OR 2`. While if we escape the `|` with a backslash like so:

```
/1\|2/
```

It becomes:

```
1|2
```